# Chrome 113 has text width rendering bug

Tags: css, google-chrome

The font width is inconsistent when same letters are arranged differently

Sample text used

```
电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由
由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电

电由
由电
```

Textarea's text width rendering has no problem
[image]

However, when the same text is written in div, the text's width becomes different. The red text (debugging) output below comes from div that is overlaid on top of textarea, the div have the exact same text and exact same style as Google Translate's textarea

[image]

To repro the problem, download https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-words-separator/gacfacdpfimbkgcnlegknnmcccjgcbnp. Then paste this sample text in https://translate.google.com

```
电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由
由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电由电

电由
由电
```

After the text is pasted, hold the Ctrl key while hovering the mouse cursor on the text's second line. You'll notice that the blue highlight is not aligned to the cloned text, this is due to the width of div's second line text becoming different when it starts with `由` instead

[image]

By the way, the problem can also be repro'd in Stackoverflow itself, while typing the question, I noticed the text width become different in Stackoverflow's question body box too, i.e.,

[image]

This problem does not happen on older version of Chrome.

This is the code that copies the textarea's style to dynamically-created div:

```
        const inputStyle = window.getComputedStyle(input);
  
        div.style.display = inputStyle.display;
        div.style.cssText = inputStyle.cssText;
        div.style.direction = inputStyle.direction;
       
        div.style.position = 'fixed';
        div.style.zIndex = Z_INDEX;
        // For some reasons, the cssText can't get all the style.
        // so we must explicitly assign those that are not assigned:
        div.style.fontSize = inputStyle.fontSize;
        div.style.fontStyle = inputStyle.fontStyle;

        div.style.fontFamily = inputStyle.fontFamily;
        div.style.fontWeight = inputStyle.fontWeight;

        div.style.whiteSpace = inputStyle.whiteSpace;
        div.style.overflow = inputStyle.overflow;
        div.style.textOverflow = inputStyle.textOverflow;

        div.style.lineHeight = inputStyle.lineHeight;
        div.style.fontStretch = inputStyle.fontStretch;

        div.style.paddingLeft = inputStyle.paddingLeft;
        div.style.paddingRight = inputStyle.paddingRight;
        div.style.paddingTop = inputStyle.paddingTop;
        div.style.paddingBottom = inputStyle.paddingBottom;

        div.style.setProperty('-webkit-font-smoothing', input.style['-webkit-font-smoothing']);

        div.style.overflowY = inputStyle.overflowY;
        div.style.overflowWrap = inputStyle.overflowWrap;

        div.style.border = inputStyle.border;
        div.style.padding = inputStyle.padding;
        div.style.outline = inputStyle.outline;
        div.style.boxSizing = inputStyle.boxSizing;
        div.style.letterSpacing = inputStyle.letterSpacing;
        div.style.resize = inputStyle.resize;
        div.style.textAlign = inputStyle.textAlign;
        div.style.textIndent = inputStyle.textIndent;
        div.style.textRendering = inputStyle.textRendering;
        div.style.wordSpacing = inputStyle.wordSpacing;
        div.style.appearance = inputStyle.appearance;
        div.style.writingMode = inputStyle.writingMode;

        const inputRect = input.getBoundingClientRect();
       
        let inputRectTop = inputRect.top;

        // Do this for the meantime while we cannot yet find the perfect way to obtain the top
        const CORNER_CASES = ['www.bing.com', 'zhidao.baidu.com'];

        if (CORNER_CASES.includes(location.hostname) && input.tagName === 'INPUT') {
            // Problems on Bing and Baidu.
            // We need to get the approximate top based on the center of
            // input's height and input's line height
            const inputLineHeight = getLineHeight(input);
            const inputPaddingTop = parseInt(inputStyle.paddingTop.replace('px', ''));
            const TEXT_CENTER_VERTICALLY
                = inputRect.height / 2 - inputLineHeight / 2 - inputPaddingTop;
            inputRectTop += TEXT_CENTER_VERTICALLY;           
        }
        div.style.top = inputRectTop + 'px';
        div.style.left = inputRect.left + 'px';

        div.style.height = inputRect.height + 'px';

        // without setting the width, google translate makes one long line for long text that wraps to new lines.
        // this fixes that problem.
        div.style.width = inputRect.width + 'px';
        div.style.color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
```

How to clone the exact dimensions of textarea's text to div? Is there another style that need to be set on latest version of Chrome?

***EDIT***

Looks like it is operating system bug. I tried to paste the same text on Visual Studio Code on older version of macOS Ventura (13.3.1). The first and second lines have same width even if the letters are re-arranged

[image]

And latest Chrome on older macOS, have no problem too:

[image]

While on newer version of macOS Ventura (13.4), the text width is inconsistent

[image]